# BigQuery - Convert TIMESTAMP to HH:MM:SS and then identify TIME_DIFF

Tags: sql, time, google-bigquery, timestamp

in BigQuery I would like to

1. Convert a TIMESTAMP (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) format to TIME (HH:MM:SS)
2. Calculate TIME_DIFF between 2 newly converted TIME points to get the *duration*

**Where I am right now**

```
SELECT
   started_at,
   ended_at,
   (ended_at - started_at) AS trip_duration,
   TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ended_at, started_at, SECOND) AS trip_duration_seconds
```

| started_at | ended_at | trip_duration | trip_duration_seconds |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-02-12 16:48:18 UTC | 2023-02-12 16:55:10 UTC | 0-0 0 0:6:52 | 412 |

**Desired result something like this**

| started_at | ended_at | trip_duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 16:48:18 | 16:55:10 | 00:06:52 |

I could probably now chop it up as STRING, and then back to a TIME format. But there must be a very easy solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider below.

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2023-02-12 16:48:18 UTC' started_at, 
         TIMESTAMP '2023-02-12 16:55:10 UTC' ended_at
)
SELECT EXTRACT(TIME FROM started_at) AS started_at,
       EXTRACT(TIME FROM ended_at) AS ended_at,
       TIME_ADD(
         TIME '0:0:0',
         INTERVAL TIMESTAMP_DIFF(ended_at, started_at, SECOND) SECOND
       ) AS trip_duration 
  FROM sample_table

-- query result
+------------+----------+---------------+
| started_at | ended_at | trip_duration |
+------------+----------+---------------+
| 16:48:18   | 16:55:10 | 00:06:52      |
+------------+----------+---------------+
```

Comment: Marvelous, that worked like a charm, thank you!