# making a new column in hh:mm:ss format from two datetime columns with UTC

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two columns in datetime format as part of a larger table with a number of null values.  [image: datetime columns]

I would like to make a new column in hh:mm:ss format that shows the difference between the times in the started_at and ended_at columns in order to fill the nulls with accurate times.

Unfortunately all the options result in a difference calculated in seconds only.

Thank you!

I wrote a query calculating the difference between started_at and ended_at values, providing me with a table of newly calculated totals in seconds.

However, I do not know how to reformat this from seconds to HH:MM:SS format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BigQuery - Convert TIMESTAMP to HH:MM:SS and then identify TIME\_DIFF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75956300/bigquery-convert-timestamp-to-hhmmss-and-then-identify-time-diff)

Comment: Unfortunately not, I am hoping to get the difference of two columns (both spanning over 4 million rows), not a smaller set of individual cells. I also want to maintain the DATETIME format for these two columns.